# How to use Selenium to run multiple TestNG.XML files simultaneously in the same browser at the same time but using different instances

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng

How to use Selenium to run multiple TestNG.XML files simultaneously in the same browser at the same time but using different instances.

I have a large number of test classes in my testng.xml file test suite.

**Testng.xml1**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite1.xml">
    <test name="Test Cases1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
        <test name="Test Cases2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Testng.xml2**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite2.xml">

    <test name="Test Cases1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
        <test name="Test Cases2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I want to run Suite1.xml and Suite2.xml simultaneously, which means that the first test cases for each suite should run in the same browser at the same time but using different instances.

I attempted to run suite-files in parallel, but it didn't work for me.

**Testng.xml3**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="RegressionSuite.xml" thread-count="10" verbose="2" parallel="test">

    <suite-files>
    
        <suite-file 
            path="Suite1.xml">
        </suite-file>
        
        <suite-file 
            path="Suite2.xml">
        </suite-file>
        
   </suite-files>
   
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Running multiple TestNG XML files simultaneously using Selenium in the same browser, but with different instances, involves a multi-threaded approach. This setup allows you to execute separate tests in parallel, each in its own browser instance. Here's how you can achieve this:

1. Preparing TestNG XML Files
   First, ensure you have your TestNG XML files configured for your tests. Suppose you have two TestNG XML files: testng1.xml and testng2.xml.
2. Configuring Selenium WebDriver for Parallel Execution
   Ensure that your test classes (TestClass1, TestClass2, etc.) are set up to instantiate their own WebDriver instance. This is crucial for parallel execution.

   public class TestClass1 {
   private WebDriver driver;

   ```
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        // Initialize the WebDriver instance
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        // Your test code here
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
   ```

   }

Repeat a similar setup for TestClass2 and any other test classes you might have.

3. Running the TestNG XML Files Simultaneously
   To run multiple TestNG XML files simultaneously, you can use a build tool like Maven or Ant, or run them programmatically.

Running with Maven (If using Maven)
If you're using Maven, you can configure the surefire-plugin in your pom.xml to run multiple suites:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And run with:

```
mvn test
```

Running Programmatically
You can also run your TestNG suites programmatically:

```
public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
        suites.add("path/to/testng1.xml"); // path to XML file.
        suites.add("path/to/testng2.xml");
        testng.setTestSuites(suites);
        testng.run();
    }
}
```

This setup starts each suite in its own thread, adhering to the parallel settings within each XML file. Each test within the suites creates its own WebDriver instance, allowing them to run in separate browser instances simultaneously.

Note:
Ensure your system has sufficient resources to handle multiple browser instances.
Test isolation is crucial when running tests in parallel; ensure your tests don't interfere with each other.
WebDriver setup (System.setProperty) path and options might need adjustments based on your specific setup and browser choice.